# Love2D setting the tile x and y

Tags: lua, positioning, love2d

I have a player tile and I want to set the x and the y for the player as a variable, but I can't seem to get it to work.

I tried putting a few numbers behind the function `drawq` but it just stretched it.

Links to full code (The important one is newgame.lua, I just put the other 2 together with it):

Line 49 - 53
   http://xedus.nl/test_builds/maploader.lua

Line 57 - 64
   http://xedus.nl/test_builds/main.lua

Line 38 - 46 http://xedus.nl/test_builds/newgame.lua

PS: Sorry, I couldn't put the code in this post, but SO keep nagging me about using the `CTRL+K`, while I did.

Comment: please post the code, your links are 404ed...

Answer (score 0):

In line 44 you have...

```
love.graphics.drawq(playertile, Quads[number2], x2, y2)
```

...(Quads). Shouldn't it be...

```
love.graphics.drawq(playertile, QuadsP[number2], x2, y2)
```

...(QuadsP) instead?

Just guessing.